# Textbox property change not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a drop down using this drop-down i trying to change the property. When first time page load it is working fine. Let's say if I select **TEXT** Works fine, if I **Number** works fine **BUT when select "Date" and then after** "Number" the textbox shows CALENDAR AS WELL AS NUMBER. Please see the image
[image]

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dpType" runat="server" Visible="true">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Type</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Text</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Number</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Date</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is my Jquery Code. I want to display calendar as shown in the image when my drop-down **value is "3".**

```
 $("#<%= dpType.ClientID %>").on('change', function () {
            //alert(this.value);
            var v = this.value;
            console.log(v);
            $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", true); 
            if (v == '0' || v == 0) {
                <%--$("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").html("");--%>
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", true); 
                $('#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>').val("");
            }

            if (v == '1' || v== "1") {
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", false); 
                $('#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>').removeClass();
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop('type', 'text');
            } else if (v == '2' || v == "2") {
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", false); 
                $('#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>').val("");
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop('type', 'number');
            } else if (v == '3' || v == "3") {
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", false); 
                $('#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>').val("");
                //$("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").prop('type', 'date');
                $("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can use [`$("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").datepicker( "destroy" )`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy)

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the value of date input not clearing when you change its class to 'datepicker' ? If yes, then try triggering the change event.

like this

```
$('#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>').val("").trigger("change");
```

It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove datepicker then you should try this:

```
$("#<%= txtTypeValue.ClientID %>").datepicker('destroy');
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply "Titus" already give me this answer and i have solve it.

Comment: Great no problem!